# Correct Rails way of using another controller's actions within another controller - subform without nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, nested-forms

I'm writing a section of an application which is "jobs to do" and jobs have notes or comments to them.

I'm never sure what the right way to use the nested resources views should be - I don't think nested_attributes_for is valid here - I may be wrong.

What I want to do is have the main #show action of the job render and at the foot, render the #index of the has_many model (which displays current comments) and then the #new of the has_many model, when I submit it sends via AJAX and adds the new comment to the bottom of the notes/comments panel.

I don't think that nested_attributes_for is right here as i'm not really submitting anything on the parent controller.

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
end

class JobNotesController < ApplicationController
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :job_notes
end

class JobNote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
end
```

In my mind it makes more sense to render the JobNotesController's #new action from within the JobsController#show so that I could effectively send someone to the raw URL: /jobs/7/jobs_notes/34

And in my mind that way would be more DRY compatible.

I'm probably over-complicating it.

### Further Info

It looks like my question was a little vague - the question is what's considered the best way to do ....

I've written many different variants of having a header/detail type scenario, what i'm not sure on is what is considered the best practice to do so and be efficient at it.

The header in this case is the job to do.  This has its own #edit method and view which makes the screen easier to work with.

When you are viewing the job, underneath its details I want to include discussion about the job - notes if you will.

I always want to show a form for adding a new note but I also want to show all the other notes attached to this job.

I can create all the relevant logic/handlers for bringing back just the last N notes and having a read further back so that the next note is in the right chronological place rather than reversing all the notes.  That bit is easy.

Its when it comes to doing forms that belong to another controller within the context of the parent controller/view.

I was heading down the route of this helper.

```
def new_job_note
  nc = JobNotesController.new
  nc.params = { :job_id = @job.id }
  nc.dispatch(:new, request)
  return c.response.body
end
```

Then in my view I can call

```
<%= new_job_note %>
```

And this actually works - so long as I setup a layout for the JobNotesController that has no surrounding tags.

It just doesn't feel like the right way to do it.

Comment: The question was whats considered the elegant way to do a sub-form of a model inside a view which has no surrounding form for the original item.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably better accomplished using partials. You can use a partial for `job_notes`, passing it the owning job as a local (or using instance variables). Also another partial for creating new notes, again passing in the owning job to render it.

You can still use AJAX to update the note list.

Comment: Ah, so something like: <%= render partial: 'job_notes/new.html.erb' %>, if I did the setup of the ivars in a helper for job_note based on the scope of job then in the JobNotesController I could use the same helper to set up the instance vars to make it more DRY?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want to do, but technically your app will always render only one action (and not index + show etc...). If you want to render block without repeating yourself, use the `render partial: 'xxx'` in your views.

Example:

- You want to render the job list (what you call index) in differents places.
- You create a file named `_job_list.html.erb`

  ```
  <% jobs.each do |j| %> ... <% end %>
  ```
- You call this block from the job#index and others actions like this:

  ```
  <%=render partial: 'job_list', locals: { jobs: @jobs } %>
  ```

Secundo, the nested ressources can be setup inside the routes like this:

```
#in routes.rb
resources :jobs do
  resources :job_notes
end
```

the show of the job_notes INSIDE jobs will point to the JobNoteController, but you will have two parameters instead of one: `job_id` and `job_note_id`.

Then you can use the two parameters `job_id` and `job_note_id` in your `JobNoteController`:

```
  class JobNoteController < ApplicationController
      def show
          @job = Job.find params[:job_id]
          @job.job_notes.find params[:job_note_id]
      end
   end
```

If you want your controller more versatile (eg. you want to have also a route pointing on /job_notes/:id, without scoping to a specific job), you can improve a bit this code:

```
  class JobNoteController < ApplicationController
      def show
          @scope = params[:job_id] ? Job.find(params[:job_id]).job_notes : JobNote
          @scope.find params[:job_note_id]
      end
   end
```

This case you will scope the query according to the context (the DRY you wanted :P)
I'm not sure if I have answered exactly what you want, feel free to explain what you want to do.

Regards,

Yacine.

Answer (score 0):

### Nesting and REST

Describing nested resources in REST is pretty simple:

```
users/1/pets
```

Tells us quite a bit about the resource straight off the bat. However there are a few things you should remember when (or before) nesting.

1. Don't nest unless the context is vital!
2. Don't nest more than one level!
3. Use shallow nesting when possible (IMHO).

So in your case you would want to use:

```
resources :jobs, shallow: true do 
  resources :jobs_notes
end
```

Which would give you

```
 GET|POST            /jobs/:job_id/jobs_notes
 GET|PATCH|DELETE    /jobs_notes/:id # no context required!
```

The reason shallow nesting is so sweet is that it lets you do `redirect_to(@child)` instead of `redirect_to([@parent, @child])` and it makes it cleaner when you have a resource that can have multiple parent types.

### What about new?

The `/new` route is a rails convention for simple resources. In other situations it might make more sense to to create resource from the parents `show` or even an `index` action. The Rails police is not going to come after if you don't have a new action.

### nested_attributes_for

`nested_attributes_for` is most often used when you want to create a parent and child record(s) at the same time.

However it is also useful if you want to create/edit multiple child records with a single request. Lets say you have class todo list app:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :list, allow_destroy: true
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
end
```

You can then create multiple `Item` records with:

```
POST /lists, { list: { items_attributes: [{ desc: 'Feed cat' }] } }
```

Or create update and delete at the same time with:

```
PATCH /lists/1, { list: {
   items_attributes: [
      { desc: 'Feed cat' }, 
      {id: '2', desc: 'new desc'}, 
      {id: '3', _destroy: '1'}
   ]
}}
```

Of course if you a creating a AJAX heavy application like a SPA it might be better to do this as individual atomic operations as nested params tend to make things complex and brittle as there are many things going on at once.

### Reusing components.

What you may actually want here is to not to re-use controller actions but rather parts of the view such as forms. Thats where [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#structuring-layouts) come in.

```
# things/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(thing) %>
  # ...
<% end %>

# parents/show.html.erb
render_partial 'things/form', thing: @parent.thing.new
```

To share code such as callbacks or actions between controllers you would use mixins as the form of modules or vertical inheritance. Note that does not mean that you can/should use multiple controller actions in a single request cycle! Rather you can this as way to avoid duplicating identical methods.

```
class TaggableController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_resource
  def create
    @tag = @resource.tag.create
    # ...
  end
end

class Posts::TagsController < TaggableController
  private
    def set_resource
      @resource = Post.find(params[:tag_id])
    end
end

class Images::TagsController < TaggableController
  private
    def set_resource
      @resource = Image.find(params[:image_id])
    end
end
```

---

```
# or use an ActiveSupport::Concern.
module Taggable
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      before_action :set_resource
    end
  end

  def create
    @tag = @resource.tag.create
    # ...
  end
end

class Posts::TagsController < ApplicationController
  include Taggable

  private
    def set_resource
      @resource = Post.find(params[:tag_id])
    end
end

class Images::TagsController < ApplicationController
  include Taggable

  private
    def set_resource
      @resource = Image.find(params[:image_id])
    end
end
```

You can even combine the two.

Comment: Sorry if the answer is a little basic - from reading the question it seems like you are a little confused about how the parts are supposed to go together rather than how to solve a specific problem.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I can come up with a few different ways to solve the problem, i'm looking for the elegant solution.  I'll post a more detailed update.